# Resume to a label not working as expected

Tags: vba

I am having an issue using Resume and although I have found another solution by using an On Error GoTo, I am still confused as to why the code below doesn't work.  The initial error occurs because the sheet name "Sheet_1" is already taken.  This means that, in the watch window, err.number has a value of 1004 just before the Resume NameAgain is executed. Rather than clear the error and jump back up to the label, an error 20 occurs(resume without error), and the code moves to the End If line.

Given that there is an active error 1004, I can't understand why it acts as though there isn't an error.  I have searched the site for Error 20 issues but nothing really resolved this for me or made me understand the logic behind it.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub ErrorTest()

Dim i as integer:i=1

NameAgain: On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Main").Name = "Sheet_" & i
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
  i = i + 1
  Resume NameAgain
End If

End Sub
```

Update after paxdiablo comment:

The above was a poor attempt at trying to replicate but simplify a problem I was having.  The section of code I am working with is below:

```
Activate CheckBook to use ActiveWindow
  CheckBook.Activate
  Set DestSheet = CheckBook.Worksheets.Add(After:=CheckBook.Sheets(1))
  On Error Resume Next
  v = 1
NameAgain:  DestSheet.Name = ExpBookName & "_" & v
                If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                    v = v + 1
                    Resume NameAgain
                End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
            Set DestCell = DestSheet.Range("A2")
```

So the solution is to move the On Error Resume Next to the label line and use GoTo in place of Resume.

Comment: No error occurred. You can't access `Err` until an error actually happens. What would you expect it to contain when there hasn't been an error at all?

Comment: The error occurs on this line: Worksheets("Main").Name = "Sheet_" & i because there is already a sheet named "Sheet_1"

Comment: Apologies Ken, the code I presented above was my attempt at a simplified version of the problem I was having with code in a much larger procedure.  The code presented above wouldn't pass the IF criteria as you rightly pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resume` statement is a means to, from *within* an error handler, go back to some point in your main (non-error-handling) code and resume execution.

In this case, you've *explicitly* stated you want to automatically `resume next` in the event of an error.

This is functionally equivalent to (VB-like pseudo-code):

```
line:
    on error goto handler
    cause error
    resume line ' not in an error handler at this point '

handler:
    resume next
```

So you're not technically *in* an error handler at the point where you try to `resume` to the label.

The *right* statement for what you're trying to do would be a simple `goto` rather than `resume`.

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, I have edited my post  due to your comment and using GoTo is indeed the solution.  I had just assumed that the use of Resume would have superseded the previous On Error Resume Next instruction, reset the 1004 to 0 and jumped to the label.  Still a newbie with VBA and your explanation makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

A more correct solution is to write code that does not deliberately generate errors or which does not use Goto.

```
Public Function GetNextSheetName(ByVal ipWb As Excel.Workbook, ByVal ipStemName As String) As String

    Dim mySheet As Variant
    Dim mySD As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set mySD = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each mySheet In ipWb.Sheets
    
        ' mySd.Count is a dummy entry to satisfy
        ' the Key and Item requirements for .Add.
        ' we are only interested in the Keys
        ' for use with the .Exists method later
        mySD.Add mySheet.Name, mySD.Count
        
    Next
    
    Do
    
        DoEvents
        
        Dim myIndex As Long
        myIndex = myIndex + 1
        
        Dim myNextSheetName As String
        myNextSheetName = ipStemName + "_" & CStr(myIndex)
        
    Loop While mySD.Exists(myNextSheetName)
    
    GetNextSheetName = myNextSheetName
       
End Function
```

Which now allows

```
    Set DestSheet = checkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=checkbook.Sheets(1))
    DestSheet.Name = GetNextSheetName(checkbook, ExpBookName)
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    Set DestCell = DestSheet.Range("A2")
```

Comment: Hi freeflow, thanks for taking the time to present another solution with the use of calling a function.  I am half way through a VBA course and I haven't yet covered creating functions in any depth. Being able to work with your solution with my own project will accelerate my learning and I am very grateful for your time.